# How to rerun test with TRYBUILD=overwrite?

Tags: testing

I want to rerun a test inside `frame-support` and overwrite the `.stderr` file with the actual error. The CI checks give me the instruction to rerun the test with the environment variable `TRYBUILD=overwrite`, but how do I do that? I tried to set the env variable in the `Cargo.toml` file like:

```rust
[env]
TRYBUILD = "overwrite"
```

but this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [a script](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/.maintain/update-rust-stable.sh) in the Substrate repo which you can use to update the pallet UI tests.
You can call it like this:

```sh
.maintain/update-rust-stable.sh 1.62
```

with the Rust version that you want to use.
This should set all env variables, thanks to @bkchr.